# Process/ProcessStartInfo Icon

Tags: .net, navision

Is it possible to define an icon for a process?
For example Like:

```
startInfo.Icon = 'C:\somepath\icon.ico';
```

The icon should be shown in the taskbar.
The only possible way (as far as I know) to achieve this is a link, but I would like to have an other option than creating a link dynamically and start it.

Comment: Where would you expect this icon to be *used*?

Comment: In the taskbar, same as the link behavior.

Comment: I believe this is done by passing the `STARTF_TITLEISLINKNAME` flag in a [`STARTUPINFO`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686331(v=vs.85).aspx) (and obviously passing the link path in the title member) when calling `CreateProcess`. Not exposed in .NET, and it needs to have a path, so you'd also be talking about creating a shell namespace extension if you truly want to avoid creating a physical file. Probably more effort than it's worth.

Comment: As far as I know @Damien_The_Unbeliever's suggestion also requires a lnk, as the title in the `STARTUPINFO` needs to be set to “the path of the shortcut file (.lnk) that the user invoked to start this process”.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The icon is associated with the executable file of that process so you can't change it. As the only workaround you may create a shortcut to the executable and set a custom icon for the shortcut. Then you can pass the path to the shortcut file into `Process.Start` (you need to add a COM reference to *Windows Script Host Object Model* via *Project > Add Reference > COM > Windows Script Host Object Model* for this to work):

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using IWshRuntimeLibrary;

class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string shortcutAddress = Environment.GetFolderPath(
            Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop) + @"\MyProcess.lnk";

        var shell = new WshShell();
        var shortcut = (IWshShortcut)shell.CreateShortcut(shortcutAddress);
        shortcut.Description = "New shortcut for a Notepad";
        shortcut.Hotkey = "Ctrl+Shift+N";
        shortcut.TargetPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(
            Environment.SpecialFolder.System) + @"\notepad.exe";
        shortcut.IconLocation = Environment.GetFolderPath(
            Environment.SpecialFolder.System) + @"\calc.exe";
        shortcut.Save();

        Process.Start(shortcutAddress);
    }
}
```